# Magento lists of category Attributes

Tags: magento, categories

I'm having a problem on how to display a certain part of the category.

For example, I want to get the name of the category which is

```
$_category->getName()
```

Getting the link would be

```
$_category->getURL()
```

There are some parts that I want to display but  don't know what's the certain function to call.
Does anyone knows a site where I can find the library for it?

```
$_category->getName()
$_category->getURL()
$_category->getImageUrl()
```

and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place is in the documentation... : http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Category.html

Comment: Oh thank god! Thanks for the reference! It helped me a lot. I'll accept the answer after a couple of minutes. :)

Comment: Good, do not hesitate to put the answer as resolved for others.

Comment: In the class reference you will not have all property ... you need to print the array _data: var_dump($_category->getData()) so see what a category contains